# spritekitでのエラーについて

Tags: ios, swift

現在spritkitでゲームを作っているのですが
登場キャラクターをシュミュレーターで動かしてみようと思ったときに、

> consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by

が最後の段に表示されランできません。

今までアプリを作っているときも
たまにこのエラーは表示されていたのですが
気づかないうちに直ってたりします。

何か解決法はあるでしょうか？

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    struct Constants {
    static let PlayerImages = ["shrimp01","shrimp02","shrimp03","shrimp04","shrimp01","shrimp02","shrimp03","shrimp04"]
     func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            }

    /// プレイヤーを構築
    func setupPlayer() {
        // Playerのパラパラアニメーション作成に必要なSKTextureクラスの配列を定義
        var playerTexture = [SKTexture]()

        // パラパラアニメーションに必要な画像を読み込む
        for imageName in Constants.PlayerImages {
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
            texture.filteringMode = .Linear
            playerTexture.append(texture)
        }

        // キャラクターのアニメーションをパラパラ漫画のように切り替える
        let playerAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(playerTexture, timePerFrame: 0.2)
        // パラパラアニメーションをループさせる
        let loopAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(playerAnimation)


     func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

            }

     func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
func setupBackgroundSea() {
    let texure = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background")
    texure.filteringMode = .Nearest


}
}
```

Comment: 提示コードは、開始括弧`{`と閉じ括弧`}`が一致してません。Xcodeのエディタから、そのままコピー&ペーストしてください。

Comment: すいません、そのままコピペしました。どこが一致してないでしょうか？

Comment: `struct Constants`の実装は、どこからどこまでですか？「どこから」はすぐにわかりますから、「どこまで」かを教えてください。

Comment: @kobocchan さん、Xcodeのエディター上でCmd-Aでテキスト全体を選択状態にした後で、Ctrl-Iで再インデントをさせることができます。普通ならその結果を見れば、どこかに`{`と`}`のミスマッチがあることはすぐわかるのですが、日頃正しいインデントを行う癖が付いていないと、それでも気がつきにくいかもしれません。また、当サイトのコードエディター機能は時々変な挙動を示すので、あなたのせいなのかサイトのせいなのかわかりませんが、とにかくあなたのコードは大変見にくい状態になっています。サイトの機能がうまく働いていないのなら手動で編集する(前の行から1行空けた後、すべての行の先頭に半角4スペースを置く)ことでコードとして表示されますので、先頭の`import SpriteKit`から最後の`}`まで、XcodeでCtrl-Iした時の状態で表示できるように編集してみてください。しっかり見ていけばその途中で足りない`}`にも気がつけると思います。